# Changing colors and line type in grid.lines

Tags: r, grid, maps, lines

I have drawn this map and arrange the elements with this code:

```
library(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(pRAA, pRAM, pCont, myleg, layout_matrix = lay)
## Left corner coordinates (0,0); right corner (1,1)
  grid.lines(c(.55,.55), c(.95,.25)) #Vertical line
  grid.lines(c(.075,.55), c(.55,.55)) # Horizontal line
```

This is the figure:
[image: map]

I would like to change the color of the horizontal line and vertical line to light gray; or change the line type to dotted. However, I am not sure that these arguments (color, linetype) are used by `grid.lines`... Any other idea on how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: change the parameters... look at the `gp=gpar(...)` argument

Comment: oh and `get.gpar()` gives pointers about what to change